# No puedo Sincronizar una función en REST con NODEJS JavaScript

Tags: javascript, nodejs, rest, restful, firebird

Tengo una Gran duda. Cuando mando a ejecutar una consulta en la base de datos de la siguiente manera, dentro de la función donde ejecuto la consulta cargo un vector o Json que esta definido fuera de dicha función como let, pero después de ejecutar la consulta no puedo ver los datos cargados en el array, pero si coloco un console.log dentro si puedo ver que se carga correctamente.

Copio el codigo para ver si es posible que me den una mano desde ya muchas gracias, estoy usando NODE js con FIREBIRD de BD

CODIGO:

```
 app.get('/productos/ConfigPF', function(req, res) {
    let tipProd = req.query.tip_prod || 0;
    tipProd = Number(tipProd);

    let idProd = req.query.id_prod || 0;
    idProd = Number(idProd);

    let arrayprod = {} // empty Object
    let key = 'ConfiracionPF';
    // empty Array, which you can push() values into
    arrayprod[key] = [];

    queryDB(`SELECT CA.ETIQUETA, CA.NOM_FORMU , CA.ID_CAMPO,CA.TIP_CARGA from tb_config_campo_pf PF,tb_config_campo CA  where pf.tip_prod = ${tipProd} and pf.id_pf = ${idProd} and pf.tip_prod = ca.tip_prod and pf.id_campo = ca.id_campo`).then(
        // success
        function(rs) {
            rs.forEach(function(row) {
                //console.log(row.IMAGEN);
                //Armar JSON
                var imagenf = ab2str(row.IMAGEN);

                var data = {
                    etiqueta: ab2str(row.ETIQUETA),
                    valor_col: ab2str(row.NOM_FORMU),
                    id_campo: row.ID_CAMPO,
                    valor: 0,
                    tip_carga: row.TIP_CARGA,
                    valor_combo: "0"
                };
                arrayprod[key].push(data);
            });
            disconnectFromDB();
            console.log(arrayprod); //Esta cargado OK
            return arrayprod
        },
        // fail
        function(err) {
            console.log(err);
            disconnectFromDB();
            return res.status(400).json({
                ok: false,
                err
            });
        }
    );    

    console.log(arrayprod); //no veo nada

    for (let i in arrayprod) {
        for (let j in arrayprod[i]) {
            if (arrayprod[i][j].tip_carga == 1) {
                arrayprod[i][j].valor_combo = "40_50"
            }
        }
    }

    res.json({
        ok: true,
        arrayprod
    })
});
```

---

Me funciono de primera instancia , el tema es que quiero hacer lo siguiente y me da por alto el for, no lo espera a que termine y continua.

Dejo el codigo:

```
app.get('/productos/ConfigPF', function(req, res) {
    //res.json('get Usuarios')
    let tipProd = req.query.tip_prod || 0;
    tipProd = Number(tipProd);

    let idProd = req.query.id_prod || 0;
    idProd = Number(idProd);

    let arrayprod = {} // empty Object
    let key = 'ConfiracionPF';
    // empty Array, which you can push() values into
    arrayprod[key] = [];

    queryDB(`SELECT CA.ETIQUETA, CA.NOM_FORMU , CA.ID_CAMPO,CA.TIP_CARGA,ID_CATG,ID_CAM_STOCK from tb_config_campo_pf PF,tb_config_campo CA  where pf.tip_prod = ${tipProd} and pf.id_pf = ${idProd} and pf.tip_prod = ca.tip_prod and pf.id_campo = ca.id_campo`)

        .then(
        // success
        (rs) => {
            // realizas operaciones con rs y llenas el array
            rs.forEach(function(row) {
                //console.log(row.IMAGEN);
                //Armar JSON
                var imagenf = ab2str(row.IMAGEN);

                var data = {
                    etiqueta: ab2str(row.ETIQUETA),
                    valor_col: ab2str(row.NOM_FORMU),
                    id_campo: row.ID_CAMPO,
                    valor: 0,
                    tip_carga: row.TIP_CARGA,
                    valor_combo: "0",
                    id_categ: row.ID_CATG,
                    id_cam_stock: row.ID_CAM_STOCK
                };
                arrayprod[key].push(data);
            });
            disconnectFromDB();
            console.log("Pase primer Select"); // verificas que tienes los datos

            let sqlsentencia = "";
            // realizas operaciones con tu array
            for (let i in arrayprod) {
                for (let j in arrayprod[i]) {
                    if (arrayprod[i][j].tip_carga == 1) {
                        if (arrayprod[i][j].id_cam_stock == 5)
                        {
                            sqlsentencia = `select CAMPO5 AS CAMPO from TB_ITEM_STOCK where id_categoria =  ${arrayprod[i][j].id_categ}`;
                        }

                        if (arrayprod[i][j].id_cam_stock == 6)
                        {
                            sqlsentencia = `select CAMPO6 AS CAMPO from TB_ITEM_STOCK where id_categoria =  ${arrayprod[i][j].id_categ}`;
                        }

                        if (arrayprod[i][j].id_cam_stock == 7)
                        {
                            sqlsentencia = `select CAMPO7 AS CAMPO from TB_ITEM_STOCK where id_categoria =  ${arrayprod[i][j].id_categ}`;
                        }

                        if (arrayprod[i][j].id_cam_stock == 8)
                        {
                            sqlsentencia = `select CAMPO8 AS CAMPO from TB_ITEM_STOCK where id_categoria =  ${arrayprod[i][j].id_categ}`;
                        }

                        if (arrayprod[i][j].id_cam_stock == 9)
                        {
                            sqlsentencia = `select CAMPO9 AS CAMPO from TB_ITEM_STOCK where id_categoria =  ${arrayprod[i][j].id_categ}`;
                        }

                        if (arrayprod[i][j].id_cam_stock == 10)
                        {
                            sqlsentencia = `select CAMPO10 AS CAMPO from TB_ITEM_STOCK where id_categoria =  ${arrayprod[i][j].id_categ}`;
                        }

                        queryDB(sqlsentencia)
                        .then((rs) =>   {
                            // realizas operaciones con rs y llenas el array
                            console.log("Pase segundo Select");
                            let valores = "";
                            rs.forEach(function(row) {
                                if (valores = "")
                                {
                                    valores = ab2str(row.CAMPO);
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    valores = valores + "_";
                                    valores = valores + ab2str(row.CAMPO);
                                }

                            });
                            arrayprod[i][j].valor_combo = valores;
                            valores = "";
                            disconnectFromDB();                        
                         },
                         (err) => {
                            console.log("error");
                        }); // termina el then()
                    }
                }
            }

            console.log(arrayprod);
           // ahora ya puedes hacer uso de res.json
           res.json({
               ok: true,
               arrayprod
           });
        },
        (err) => {
            console.log("error");
        }); // termina el then()
}); // termina el app.get()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**PROBLEMA**

El problema está en que intentas realizar operaciones con tu `array` antes que este contenga datos.

Tu llamada a la función `queryDB()` es asíncrona. Por lo tanto, cuando las operaciones realizadas por esta función devuelvan algún valor, *entonces* se ejecutarán las acciones que se encuentran dentro de `then()`. Mientras eso sucede, javascript continuará ejecutando las instrucciones que existan después de tu llamada a `queryDB`. Y es por esa razón que el `array` está vacío al momento que ejecutas tu `console.log()` y seguirá estando vacío mientras no se ejecuten las operaciones dentro de `then()` y se llenen los datos de tu `array`.

**SOLUCIÓN**

Para solucionar tu problema, tienes algunas opciones: usar *async/await*, crear un wrapper que devuelva una *promesa* o mover tus instrucciones dentro del `then()`

Haremos esto último ya que es lo más rápido de aplicar y no te enredo con *Promises* o *async/await*.

Tu código podría quedar así:

```
app.get('/productos/ConfigPF', (req, res) => {
    // realizas las operaciones con req
    let arrayprod = {} // inicias tu array
    // realizas operaciones con tu array
    queryDB(sqlStatement)
        .then(
            // success
            (rs) => {
                // realizas operaciones con rs y llenas el array
                console.log(arrayprod); // verificas que tienes los datos
                // realizas operaciones con tu array
                for (let i in arrayprod) {
                    for (let j in arrayprod[i]) {
                        if (arrayprod[i][j].tip_carga == 1) {
                            arrayprod[i][j].valor_combo = "40_50"
                        }
                    }
                }
               // ahora ya puedes hacer uso de res.json
               res.json({
                   ok: true,
                   arrayprod
               });
            },
            (err) => {
                // manejas tu error
            }); // termina el then()
        }); // termina el app.get()
```

De esta forma ya debe funcionar. Espero que sea la respuesta que buscabas.

Comment: Deje una respuesta Mauricio seria de mucha ayuda si me podridas dar una mano