# NODE.JS Dentro de llamado get de un REST la sentencia sigue sin esperar que finalice un for

Tags: javascript, nodejs, rest, restful, firebird

Tengo el siguiente problema:
Cuando ejecuto la sentencia SQL y logro cargar el array, me muestra el primer console.log con el mensaje "Pase primer select", luego pasa por un for donde tiene otra subquery que terminaría de cargar el array, el tema es que lo pasa por alto y me muestra el console.log con el array final, pero, luego me muestra el resultado de la subquery, es como que no esperara al for para finalizar, tienen idea de como lo podría solventar al tema? me vendría de muchísima ayuda. desde ya muchas gracias y Saludos.

*Codigo:*

```
app.get('/productos/ConfigPF', function(req, res) {
    //res.json('get Usuarios')
    let tipProd = req.query.tip_prod || 0;
    tipProd = Number(tipProd);

    let idProd = req.query.id_prod || 0;
    idProd = Number(idProd);

    let arrayprod = {} // empty Object
    let key = 'ConfiracionPF';
    // empty Array, which you can push() values into
    arrayprod[key] = [];

    queryDB(`SELECT CA.ETIQUETA, CA.NOM_FORMU , CA.ID_CAMPO,CA.TIP_CARGA,ID_CATG,ID_CAM_STOCK from tb_config_campo_pf PF,tb_config_campo CA  where pf.tip_prod = ${tipProd} and pf.id_pf = ${idProd} and pf.tip_prod = ca.tip_prod and pf.id_campo = ca.id_campo`)

        .then(
        // success
        (rs) => {
            // realizas operaciones con rs y llenas el array
            rs.forEach(function(row) {
                //console.log(row.IMAGEN);
                //Armar JSON
                var imagenf = ab2str(row.IMAGEN);

                var data = {
                    etiqueta: ab2str(row.ETIQUETA),
                    valor_col: ab2str(row.NOM_FORMU),
                    id_campo: row.ID_CAMPO,
                    valor: 0,
                    tip_carga: row.TIP_CARGA,
                    valor_combo: "0",
                    id_categ: row.ID_CATG,
                    id_cam_stock: row.ID_CAM_STOCK
                };
                arrayprod[key].push(data);
            });
            disconnectFromDB();
            console.log("Pase primer Select"); // verificas que tienes los datos

            let sqlsentencia = "";
            // realizas operaciones con tu array
            for (let i in arrayprod) {
                for (let j in arrayprod[i]) {
                    if (arrayprod[i][j].tip_carga == 1) {
                        if (arrayprod[i][j].id_cam_stock == 5)
                        {
                            sqlsentencia = `select CAMPO5 AS CAMPO from TB_ITEM_STOCK where id_categoria =  ${arrayprod[i][j].id_categ}`;
                        }

                        if (arrayprod[i][j].id_cam_stock == 6)
                        {
                            sqlsentencia = `select CAMPO6 AS CAMPO from TB_ITEM_STOCK where id_categoria =  ${arrayprod[i][j].id_categ}`;
                        }

                        if (arrayprod[i][j].id_cam_stock == 7)
                        {
                            sqlsentencia = `select CAMPO7 AS CAMPO from TB_ITEM_STOCK where id_categoria =  ${arrayprod[i][j].id_categ}`;
                        }

                        if (arrayprod[i][j].id_cam_stock == 8)
                        {
                            sqlsentencia = `select CAMPO8 AS CAMPO from TB_ITEM_STOCK where id_categoria =  ${arrayprod[i][j].id_categ}`;
                        }

                        if (arrayprod[i][j].id_cam_stock == 9)
                        {
                            sqlsentencia = `select CAMPO9 AS CAMPO from TB_ITEM_STOCK where id_categoria =  ${arrayprod[i][j].id_categ}`;
                        }

                        if (arrayprod[i][j].id_cam_stock == 10)
                        {
                            sqlsentencia = `select CAMPO10 AS CAMPO from TB_ITEM_STOCK where id_categoria =  ${arrayprod[i][j].id_categ}`;
                        }

                        queryDB(sqlsentencia)
                        .then((rs) =>   {
                            // realizas operaciones con rs y llenas el array
                            console.log("Pase segundo Select");
                            let valores = "";
                            rs.forEach(function(row) {
                                if (valores = "")
                                {
                                    valores = ab2str(row.CAMPO);
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    valores = valores + "_";
                                    valores = valores + ab2str(row.CAMPO);
                                }

                            });
                            arrayprod[i][j].valor_combo = valores;
                            valores = "";
                            disconnectFromDB();                        
                         },
                         (err) => {
                            console.log("error");
                        }); // termina el then()
                    }
                }
            }

            console.log(arrayprod);
           // ahora ya puedes hacer uso de res.json
           res.json({
               ok: true,
               arrayprod
           });
        },
        (err) => {
            console.log("error");
        }); // termina el then()
}); // termina el app.get()
```

---

Realize las modificaciones llsanchez y me da el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Te paso el codigo que escribi para este caso, desde ya muchas gracias!

CODIGO:

```
app.get('/productos/ConfigPF', function(req, res) {
    //res.json('get Usuarios')
    let tipProd = req.query.tip_prod || 0;
    tipProd = Number(tipProd);

    let idProd = req.query.id_prod || 0;
    idProd = Number(idProd);

    let arrayprod = {} // empty Object
    let key = 'ConfiracionPF';
    // empty Array, which you can push() values into
    arrayprod[key] = [];

    queryDB(`SELECT CA.ETIQUETA, CA.NOM_FORMU , CA.ID_CAMPO,CA.TIP_CARGA,ID_CATG,ID_CAM_STOCK from tb_config_campo_pf PF,tb_config_campo CA  where pf.tip_prod = ${tipProd} and pf.id_pf = ${idProd} and pf.tip_prod = ca.tip_prod and pf.id_campo = ca.id_campo`)

        .then(
        // success
        (rs) => {
            // realizas operaciones con rs y llenas el array
            rs.forEach(function(row) {
                //console.log(row.IMAGEN);
                //Armar JSON
                var imagenf = ab2str(row.IMAGEN);

                var data = {
                    etiqueta: ab2str(row.ETIQUETA),
                    valor_col: ab2str(row.NOM_FORMU),
                    id_campo: row.ID_CAMPO,
                    valor: 0,
                    tip_carga: row.TIP_CARGA,
                    valor_combo: "0",
                    id_categ: row.ID_CATG,
                    id_cam_stock: row.ID_CAM_STOCK
                };
                arrayprod[key].push(data);
            });
            disconnectFromDB();
            console.log("Pase primer Select"); // verificas que tienes los datos

            let sqlsentencia = "";
            let promises = {};

            for(let i in arrayprod) {
                for(let j in arrayprod[i]) {

                    if (arrayprod[i][j].tip_carga == 1) {

                    if (arrayprod[i][j].id_cam_stock == 5)
                    {
                        sqlsentencia = `select DISTINCT CAMPO5 AS CAMPO from TB_ITEM_STOCK where id_categoria =  ${arrayprod[i][j].id_categ}`;
                    }

                    if (arrayprod[i][j].id_cam_stock == 6)
                    {
                        sqlsentencia = `select DISTINCT CAMPO6 AS CAMPO from TB_ITEM_STOCK where id_categoria =  ${arrayprod[i][j].id_categ}`;
                    }

                    if (arrayprod[i][j].id_cam_stock == 7)
                    {
                        sqlsentencia = `select  DISTINCT CAMPO7 AS CAMPO from TB_ITEM_STOCK where id_categoria =  ${arrayprod[i][j].id_categ}`;
                    }

                    if (arrayprod[i][j].id_cam_stock == 8)
                    {
                        sqlsentencia = `select  DISTINCT CAMPO8 AS CAMPO from TB_ITEM_STOCK where id_categoria =  ${arrayprod[i][j].id_categ}`;
                    }

                    if (arrayprod[i][j].id_cam_stock == 9)
                    {
                        sqlsentencia = `select DISTINCT CAMPO9 AS CAMPO from TB_ITEM_STOCK where id_categoria =  ${arrayprod[i][j].id_categ}`;
                    }

                    if (arrayprod[i][j].id_cam_stock == 10)
                    {
                        sqlsentencia = `select DISTINCT CAMPO10 AS CAMPO from TB_ITEM_STOCK where id_categoria =  ${arrayprod[i][j].id_categ}`;
                    }

                    let valores = "";

                    promises[`${i}|${j}`] = queryDB(sqlsentencia); //Solo la guardas, no la ejecutas.
                    // Lo guardamos en un objeto, el motivo por el que la clave del objeto es `i|j` 
                    //es para que cuando se resuelvan las promesas, sepas que resultado corresponde a que query
                    console.log("Recupero Query");
                    }
                }
            } //fin de los for
            // Fuera del los for:

            Promise.all(promises)
            .then(result => {
                //result es un objeto con la siguiente estructura --> {'i1|j1' : (resultado), 'i1|j2: (resultado2), ...}
                Object.keys(result).forEach(K => {
                    const [i, j] = K.split('|');

                    const rs = result[K];
                    let valores = '';
                    rs.forEach(function(row) {
                        if (valores = "")
                        {
                            valores = ab2str(row.CAMPO);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            valores = valores + "_";
                            valores = valores + ab2str(row.CAMPO);
                        }               
                    });
                    valores = '';
                    arrayprod[i][j].valor_combo = valores;
                });
                // Aqui ya deberías tener todas las queries resueltas y podrás resolver tu petición.
                res.json({
                        ok: true,
                        arrayprod
                });
            })
            .catch(result => console.log(result));

        },
        (err) => {
            console.log("error");
        }); // termina el then()
```

Comment: Hola. Como bien te plantean en la respuesta, el tema es la asincronía de la función `queryDB()`, que fue lo que te respondí la vez pasada. Ahora que veo el código un poco más completo, entiendo lo que quieres hacer, aunque no sé si hay forma de mejorar la eficiencia para que no debas realizar 2 o más peticiones a la BD. Así tu código se vería un poco menos complejo y todo sería más eficiente. Lo estudiaré a ver que se me ocurre. Saludos

Comment: Muchas gracias Mauricio tu aporte seria de muchisima ayuda

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [No puedo Sincronizar una función en REST con NODEJS JavaScript](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/246385/no-puedo-sincronizar-una-funci%c3%b3n-en-rest-con-nodejs-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

Tiene sentido lo que comentas, lo que ocurre es que en tu `for` anidado estas lanzando consultas asincronas. Me intento explicar, por cada iteración lanzas una query que finalizara cuando sea, a priori no lo sabes. Tu petición `get` se esta completando antes de que se finalicen tus subconsultas.

Una solución pasaría por utilizar `Promise.all`. Para ello, en lugar de ejecutar cada consulta en el `for` deberás almacenarlas en un array  o un objeto para luego ejecutarlas y recibir la respuesta de todas antes de resolver las demas:

```js
let promises = {};

for(let i in arrayprod) {
    for(let j in arrayprod[i]) {
        ...

        promises[`${i}|${j}`] = queryDB(sqlsentencia); //Solo la guardas, no la ejecutas.
        // Lo guardamos en un objeto, el motivo por el que la clave del objeto es `i|j` 
        //es para que cuando se resuelvan las promesas, sepas que resultado corresponde a que query
    }
} //fin de los for
```

Ahora, tenemos un objeto con todas las promesas que aun no se han ejecutado, por lo que todo el código hasta ahora se ha ejecutado de forma sincrona.

Para resolver esas query tenemos `Promise.all` que toma como parámetro un `array` o un `object`:

```js
// Fuera del los for:

Promise.all(promises)
   .then(result => {
        //result es un objeto con la siguiente estructura --> {'i1|j1' : (resultado), 'i1|j2: (resultado2), ...}
        Object.keys(result).forEach(K => {
            const [i, j] = K.split('|');

            const rs = result[K];
            let valores = '';
            rs.forEach(function(row) {
                if (valores = "")
                {
                    valores = ab2str(row.CAMPO);
                }
                else
                {
                    valores = valores + "_";
                    valores = valores + ab2str(row.CAMPO);
                }               
            });
            valores = '';
            arrayprod[i][j].valor_combo = valores;
        });
        // Aqui ya deberías tener todas las queries resueltas y podrás resolver tu petición.
         res.json({
               ok: true,
               arrayprod
           });
   }
)
```

Espero haber sido claro y que te sirva de ayuda.

Comment: Muchas gracias LLsanchez.  Voy a probar la codificación y te aviso